# Ajax reset session php

Tags: php, ajax, session

I use my own Framework, in localhost all works perfectly fine but not on the server.

I'm logged, so I've a session id.

On a ajax request, the php script doesn't keep my session, if I return the session, the session are empty but me in my side, I keep the session.

It's like if the server thinks the ajax request is a new user.

I don't know where to look and I can't post all the framework code here...
Yesterday I already have this issue (at work) then at home, I retested and all worked great...

I don't get it...

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit', function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ROOT+"list",
        data: {id:id},
        headers: { 
            Accept : "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data.sess.ROLE);
            if(data.status == "error"){
                //error
            }else{
                //ok
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Controller:

```
public function editAction(){
    //if(!$this->ROLE('tokayn')){ $this->redirectUrl('thread_index'); }

    if(Request::POST()){
        if(is_int($_POST['id'])){
            $user = $this->batiments->findById($_POST['id']);
            if($user->id_proprio == $_SESSION['id']){ 
                $data = array('status'=>'ok', 'message'=>$user);
                Request::renderJson($data);                         
            }else{
                Request::renderJson(array('sess'=>$_SESSION));  
                //$data = array('status'=>'error', 'message'=>'error');
                //Request::renderJson($data);   
            }
        }else{
            $data = array('status'=>'error', 'message'=>'error');
            Request::renderJson($data);     
        }
    }else{  
        //$this->redirectUrl('thread_index');
    }
}
```

If a user is not logged, the session role is 'visitor' but if he's logged, the session role is 'connected'.

I've a echo before the ajax form and it's 'connected'.
Then, on submit the ajax form, the ajax request return 'visitor' but if I refresh, I keep the 'connected' echo...

Comment: Try analyzing the request headers being sent with the ajax request (`var_dump($_SERVER, $_REQUEST)`). Maybe something is in there that is telling your framework not to consider the session. Also, it looks like you're using a php framework, which one is it? Maybe it does not look at the sessions for ajax requests?

Comment: I've faced this issue for me the problem was I was using `https://server:1234/somecontroller` while i was requesting from ajax as `http://server:3344/somecontroller`, and session was not shared between https and http so double check if this apply for you.

Comment: I can't ask about your server `URL` so make sure that you are using correct urls. Otherwise your server will assign you a new session id for first time which will not be authenticated...

Comment: @ɢʜʘʂʈʀɛɔʘɴ yep that was it!
I was using http:// www. and not http://

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've faced this issue for me the problem was I was using

`https://server:1234/somecontroller`

while i was requesting from ajax as

`http://server:3344/somecontroller`

and session was not shared between https and http so double check if this apply for you.